# How to find the narrowest point in path between two cells in grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-physics

I am writing bot for rts game ( one village against another on grid map, there is also crossable cells - grass, forest- and noncrossable cells - water, hills). How to find the narrowest point on path between those two cells ? Any suggestion for algorithm ? (I am using A* to find closest path and I want to bot decide where to put Tower (strong defensive building) , to put on the narrowest point so enemy cannot cross around - probably can, depends  on map, but is less possible ).

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas.

Think about a (maybe too much) simplified version, on which X stands for noncrossable cells, . stands for crossable, A stands for a village and B stands for another.

```
XXXA.XXXXX
XXX..XXXXX
XX.....XXX
XXX....XXX
XXX...XXXX
XXX.....XX
XXXX....XX
XXXX.BXXXX
```

Since there's no "branch" on the road connecting the two village, we can transfer the map into

```
    000A100000
    0001100000
    0011111000
    0001111000
   C0001110000D
    0001111100
    0000111100
    00001B0000
```

on which 0 and 1 means the cost to travel on a cell. The narrowest point on the road is the path that cost the minimal to travel from C to D. The path is indicated by # in the following map

```
    000A100000
    ##########
    #01111100#
    #00111100#
   C#00111000#D
    0001111100
    0000111100
    00001B0000
```

Since only the cells on the "road" of the original map cost more than 0, the shortest path that minimize the cost between C and D will indeed gives a clue of location of the "narrowest point" on the road.

Well this is just a simplified version since there's only one "main road" connecting the two villages. But I hope it could somehow point in the right direction of a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind this is not even necessarily what you want. Consider a tower `T` with attack range `t`

```
..t..
.ttt.
ttTtt
.ttt.
..t..
```

and a branching map where there is one narrow direct path and one wide indirect path from point `A` to point `B`. Assume the immediate points around `A` marked `n` are walkable, but not build-able for towers.

```
xBxxxxxxx
x.......x
x.......x
x.......x
x..xx...x
x..xx...x
x..xx...x
x.......x
xnnn....x
xnnn....x
xAnxxxxxx
```

Initially, characters will follow path `p`

```
xBxxxxxxx
xp......x
xp......x
xp......x
xp.xx...x
xp.xx...x
xp.xx...x
xp......x
xp......x
xp......x
xA.xxxxxx
```

Placing `T` on the narrowest point, would cause 3 hits if the characters continued on the same path. But this is not what will happen if the pain of the tower is high with respect to the goal of speed, e.g. certainly if fatal. Instead, characters will be diverted to the longer path.

```
xBxxxxxxx
xp......x
xppppp..x
x.t..p..x
xttxxp..x
xtTxxp..x
xttxxp..x
x.t..p..x
x....p..x
xppppp..x
xA.xxxxxx
```

The better placement in this case is the one that guarantees at least one hit. (Keep in mind that the very best placements of `T` closer to `A` is assumed to be non-build-able.)

```
xBxxxxxxx
x.......x
x.......x
x.......x
x..xx...x
x..xx...x
x.txx...x
xttTtt..x
x.ttt...x
x..t....x
xA.xxxxxx
```

So, what you may want is a placement of `T` that maximizes the cost of minimum cost path that will be calculated *after* the placement of `T`. Look into maximin (minimax) algorithms. Of course, there other other things to consider with the placement, such as defensibility of the tower itself.

Comment: For fixed maps, i.e. ones not randomly generated, it may serve well to predetermine some ideal placement spots to use as heuristics. Obviously game play may change the dynamic, but these heuristic spots would allow for pruning of your search tree.